# Rails / Google SSO - auth popup causing: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-apps, google-sso

I have a Rails app that uses Google SSO to sign in / up users. It works fine in Safari, but in Chrome I keep getting this error:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "[domain]" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I have previously used this "solution" to solve it: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/122#issuecomment-60510241

But I recently noticed that it suddenly stopped working for Safari with the above solution instead.

My current implementation looks like this (coffee script):

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax
    url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plus.js?onload=gpAsyncInit'
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: false

window.gpAsyncInit = ->

  $('.googleplus-login').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()

  gapi.auth.authorize {
    immediate: false
    response_type: 'code'
    cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin'
    client_id: '[id]'
    scope: 'email profile'
  }, (response) ->
    if response and !response.error
      # google authentication succeed, now post data to server and handle data  securely
      jQuery.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: '/auth/google_oauth2/callback'
        dataType: 'json'
        data: response
        success: (json) ->
          # response from server
          [this doesn't happen]

          return
    else
      # google authentication failed
```

I haven't seen this error described anywhere in Google's documentation, so I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

I'm sure that I have the same protocol `https`, so it must be something else. I'm guessing the domain.

I've seen that other sites (like Stack-overflow) uses a different flow where a popup isn't displayed but the user instead gets redirected to another page. Wonder if that could be a solution (and / or) the recommended way to do it to avoid my error.

In that case, where can I find documentation for this in Google's documentation jungle?

**Update**

This is the relevant parts of my controller code.

```
def google_authentication

  respond_to do |format|

    code = params[:code]

    unless code.blank?

      [..]

      load = { code: code, client_id: client_id, client_secret: client_secret, grant_type: grant_type, redirect_uri: redirect_uri }
      url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token/"
      response = HTTParty.post(url, :query => load, headers: { "content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)

      unless json.nil?

        unless json["error"].present?

          [..]

          email = decoded_hash["email"]
          user = User.find_by_email(email)

          if user
            sign_in_existing_user(user)
            format.json { render :json => {:status => "Success", user_id: "# {user.id}"} }
          else
            # Create user
            [..]
            format.html { redirect_to current_user, notice: "Welcome #{current_user.name}!" }
            format.json { render :json => {:status => "Success", user_id: "#{current_user.id}"} }

          end
        else
          #format.html { redirect_to root_path, error: "Could not sign up / in" }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have updated my JS based on the answer below by @EugZol, to:

```
data: {access_token: response['access_token'], error: response['error'], expires_in: response['expires_in']}
```

And I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Started POST "/auth/google_oauth2/callback" [..]
Processing by UsersController#google_authentication as JSON
Parameters: {"expires_in"=>"86400", "provider"=>"google_oauth2"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:237:in `google_authentication'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could assume that here, when you are trying to make request to your own server:

```
data: response
```

...your code is accessing in an indirect way a frame created by GAPI. I.e., `response` object references in one of its internal fields that frame, and jQuery is trying to serialize that.

The solution is to pick required fields manually:

```
data: {
  state: response['state'],
  code: response['code'],
  scope: response['scope'],
  client_id: response['client_id'],
  g_user_cookie_policy: response['g_user_cookie_policy']
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I tried it I get the following error: `Started POST "/auth/google_oauth2/callback" [...]
Processing by UsersController#google_authentication as JSON
  Parameters: {"expires_in"=>"[exp]", "provider"=>"google_oauth2"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:237:in google_authentication'`. Will update my question with the relevant controller code as well, will be very thankful if you could take a look at it as well!

Comment: You seem to need to pass `code` parameter as well. Add `{code: response['code'], ...}` to the Javascript's `data` as well.

Comment: Thank you! Now it finally works! This is the parameters I actually used (access token doesn't exist for me here) `data: { state: response['state'], code: response['code'], scope: response['scope'], client_id: response['client_id'], g_user_cookie_policy: response['g_user_cookie_policy'] }`.

Comment: You are welcome! I edited my answer to reflect actual hash key names.